# In Upstart mode it says that it can't mount /media/sdb2, how do i fix this?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I tried mounting my Windows partition so I could access my files, after shutting down windows in cmd by running shutdown /s I can no longer access my Linux partition. So I guess I have broken Linux, how can i fix this?

Comment: where does it fail? do you get the grub menu?

Comment: I can get too the grub, from there i can get into Windows 10, but when i try to boot into Ubuntu during boot it takes me to the maintenance command line (or was it emergency? i can't quite remember). When i try to boot in Upstart mode it says it can't mount /media/sdb2, then it seems to freeze, though the circles at the bottom continue. I've also attempted to use recovery mode, i tried everything in it (with the exception of making more space because i don't see how that would fix it). So right now the only way i can use Linux is through the maintenance command line.

Comment: if you don't get the splash screen, it is likely that initramfs cant find the root drive or can't mount a drive.  double check the uuid's you used in the fstab for the problem install. if your install cd let's you open ashen in the install do "update-initramfs -u"

Comment: I can already get to the splash screen, when i try to boot into ubuntu it takes me to the splash screen and then it takes me to the maintenance line.

Comment: ok, likely  one of the drive in fstab is incorrect. in grub hilight the entery and press "e" to edit. change "splash" to "nosplash"  look for a drive mount failure. that will be the one that needs to be corrected

Comment: ok, i'll try that and see if it works

Comment: What do you mean open ashen? Also i didn't install from a cd i installed from an external HDD, would that change anything? When i searched what ashen was google only came up with a game. I presume it isn't that. Also everything goes to fast when i remove the splash screen for me to see which drive is incorrect.

Comment: a command shell.. sorry for the typo. anyway you need to fix /etc/fstab then update-initramrs -u.  you maybe able to do it fron the command prompt

Comment: So, I found what was ACTUALLY being the problem, turns out even though I restarted Windows, turned off fast boot, etc. apparently I had to increase the file size of Windows hibernation file by 75% for me to be able to turn it off properly and after I did that Windows properly shut down and Linux began working again. I'm not sure what caused Linux to have this bizarre reaction with Windows being in a half-off half-hibernated state but I guess everything's fixed now. I can even finally access my files on my Windows partition from Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Get into your windows machine. Then download the ISO for the Ubuntu version you are running and make a live boot flash drive with `unetbootin`. After that reboot and install Ubuntu to the same partition as the faulty Ubuntu, but do not format the partition while choosing and setting up partitions. As long as you don't format your partition, GRUB will be fixed and you will still have all your packages.

Comment: the installer will erase all directories where it installs. I believe he was trying to avoid a reinstall

Comment: no. the installer will not erase directories and will only install the missing packages and configuration files. Obviously you will receive a warning that there might be conflicts. But even if there are any conflicts, the new install will just interrupt and your system will remain the same as when you started. So you really don't have much to lose by doing what I suggested.

Comment: all system directories will be ereased. the installer will erase any directory that it writes into to prevent brakage from mismatched dependencies. that means that he will lose all packages he has installed. telling the installer not to format will only save the home diretory.

Comment: I've tried it and worked fine for me.. your should try it on a linux box that you would be willing to take a risk on - and you'll see.

Comment: enrias -- I have done it many times ....  6 in the last week.